# converting image source into file and append the file in rest api

Tags: angularjs, base64, image-upload

I have an image source , i need to convert it into png file and append it to backend and send. upload is successfull ,but when we retrieve the stored file from backend , it has invalid file format error. I think it was not converted to base64 and because of this we have this issue. I am using $base64 dependency to covert my source.

```
 source = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADICAYAAACtWK6eAAAgAElEQVR4Xjy9Z6xlaXYdts6999ycc3o5p6pXVV3V1Xl6unt62CI5nCFFw6RoyIZtSDIMWTb8wyBk2DBgyYZ/CIT+SJRJGDJNWrboiRRnunu6OR0qp5fq5XRzzjkcY+03ozcoVNebV/eee8639157rbV3Kf/kj35XazbbsFrtqJSa2Ns9Qj5XQa8LOOw+mE0O1Kt9WCxOVCtN5HMlmMx=="

   $scope.uploadFile = function(source){

        var imageBase64 = $base64.encode(source);
        var blob = new Blob([imageBase64], {
            type: 'image/png'
        });
        var filename = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
        var file = new File([blob], filename + '.png',{type:'image/png'});
        $scope.file = file;

               var json = {
            "json": {
                "request":{
                    "servicetype":"4",
                    "functiontype": "4012",
                     "session":{
                    "sessionid":session
                }

                }
            }
        };

        fileUpload.uploadFileToEmp( json, file ).then(function(res){

                } 
            }
        });


       }
```

Comment: I think it failed because your source is an invalid `base64`

Comment: Any solutions ? I didnt gave my full source here. I just given for eg..